# TypeScript: check types compatibility

Tags: typescript, types

From two representations of TypeScript types, which could be strings like:

A:

```
{
    a: string
    b: number
}
```

B:

```
{
    a: string
}
```

How can I programmatically test if they are compatible, answering the question "can I assign a variable of type A to a value of type B?" (or vice-versa).

The function would look like this:

```
function match(source: string, target: string): boolean { /** */ }

match('number', 'any') // true
match('any', 'number') // false
match('{a: string; b: number}', '{a: string; b: number}') // true
match('{a: string; b: number}', '{a: string}') // true
match('{a: string}', '{a: string; b: number}') // false
// ...
```

What is the simplest way of doing that?

EDIT: The use case is that I have custom user generated type interfaces and I want to check if they are compatible on design time. TypeScript is just the syntax being used for expressing those types, but this is secondary to the challenge of asserting type matching. It could be any other type system.

Comment: Typescript types and interfaces don't exist at runtime, just FYI.

Comment: As @matmo mentioned TypeScript is there to prevent such things from happening and statically and not dynamically. What is the use case of yours. Its better to share your use case instead in this case

Comment: Any specific use case is unnecessary for this simple question, but here it goes: I have custom user generated type interfaces and I want to check if they are compatible on design time. TypeScript is just the syntax that is being used for expressing those types, but this is secondary to the challenge of asserting type matching. It could be any other type system. @TarunLalwani

Comment: @Samuel When you say you want to check at design time, does this mean you want to perform this check as part of your build step ? And not at runtime ? When would this compatibility check be invoked and how ? If this is done at build time in some node script, we could use the compiler API to achieve this. If this is at runtime using the compiler, while still possible would have a big overhead.

Comment: We can call it runtime since there is a program running checking for type compatibility between user generated types. How would you use the compiler at runtime for that matter? Is there a way of extracting the specific part of the compiler that does this type compatibility check? @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bring in the compiler as a npm package (just run `npm install typescript`) and use the compiler in your code. The solution below, just creates a small program to test the compatibility of the two types. Performance may be an issue, so try it with your real world use-case and see if it is acceptable:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'

// Cache declarations (lib.d.ts for example) to improve performance
let sourceFileCache: { [name: string]: ts.SourceFile | undefined } = {};
function match(source: string, target: string): boolean {
    let host = ts.createCompilerHost({});
    let originalGetSourceFile = host.getSourceFile;
    host.getSourceFile = (fileName, languageVersion, onError?, shouldCreateNewSourceFile?) => {
        // You can add more virtual files, or let the host default read the from the disk
        if (fileName === "compatCheck.ts") {
            return ts.createSourceFile(fileName, `
type Source = ${source};
type Target = ${target};

let source!: Source;
let target!: Target;
target = source;
`, languageVersion);
        }

        // Try to get source file from cache, will perfrom better if we reuse the parsed source file.
        if (sourceFileCache[fileName] === undefined) {
            return sourceFileCache[fileName] = originalGetSourceFile(fileName, languageVersion, onError, shouldCreateNewSourceFile);
        } else {
            return sourceFileCache[fileName];
        }
    }

    let program = ts.createProgram(["compatCheck.ts"], {

    }, host);
    let errors = program.getSemanticDiagnostics();
    return !errors.some(e => true);
}

console.log(match('number', 'any')); // true any can be assigned to number
console.log(match('any', 'number')); // true number can be assigned to any as well 
console.log(match('{a: string; b: number}', '{a: string; b: number}')); // true
console.log(match('{a: string; b: number}', '{a: string}')); // true
console.log(match('{a: string}', '{a: string; b: number}')); // false
```

**Edit**

A version that should perform better is if you don't parse any of the default `lib.d.ts` and just provide the minimal types required for the compiler to work. This is a surprisingly small set (`Array`, `Boolean`, `Number`, `Function`, `IArguments`, `Object`, `RegExp` and `String). We can also not include any of the methods in these type and just provide a simple definition that keeps the types incompatible. If you need any other types you will have to add the explicitly, but that should be simple enough. If you want to allow usage of any of the methods on these types you will need to add those as well but my understanding of you use-case, is you that you just want to compare interfaces for compatibility so this should not be an issue:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

// Cache declarations (lib.d.ts for example) to improve performance
let sourceFileCache: { [name: string]: ts.SourceFile | undefined } = {};
function match(source: string, target: string): boolean {
    let host = ts.createCompilerHost({});
    let originalGetSourceFile = host.getSourceFile;
    host.directoryExists = ()=> false;
    host.fileExists = fileName => fileName === "compatCheck.ts";
    host.getSourceFile = (fileName, languageVersion, onError?, shouldCreateNewSourceFile?) => {
        // You can add more virtual files, or let the host default read the from the disk
        if (fileName === "compatCheck.ts") {
            return ts.createSourceFile(fileName, `
// Compiler Reuired Types
interface Array<T> { isArray: T & true }
type Boolean = { isBoolean: true }
type Function = { isFunction: true }
type IArguments = { isIArguments: true }
type Number = { isNumber: true }
type Object = { isObject: true }
type RegExp = { isRegExp: true }
type String = { isString: true }

type Source = ${source};
type Target = ${target};

let source!: Source;
let target!: Target;
target = source;
`, languageVersion);
        }

        // Try to get source file from cache, will perfrom better if we reuse the parsed source file.
        if (sourceFileCache[fileName] === undefined) {
            return sourceFileCache[fileName] = originalGetSourceFile(fileName, languageVersion, onError, shouldCreateNewSourceFile);
        } else {
            return sourceFileCache[fileName];
        }
    }

    let program = ts.createProgram(["compatCheck.ts"], {
        noLib: true // Don't parse any default lib, we provide our own types
    }, host);
    let errors = program.getSemanticDiagnostics()
        .concat(program.getDeclarationDiagnostics())
        .concat(program.getConfigFileParsingDiagnostics())
        .concat(program.getGlobalDiagnostics())
        .concat(program.getOptionsDiagnostics())
        .concat(program.getSyntacticDiagnostics());
    return !errors.some(e => true);
}

console.log(match('number', 'any')); // true any can be assigned to number
console.log(match('any', 'number')); // true number can be assigned to any as well 
console.log(match('{a: string; b: number}', '{a: string; b: number}')); // true
console.log(match('{a: string; b: number}', '{a: string}')); // true
console.log(match('{a: string}', '{a: string; b: number}')); // false
```

Comment: You can use a static, cached instance of the language service and swap out the code for a single SourceFile every time you check new types.  That way it never needs to re-parse core lib declarations.

Comment: @cspotcode true, that should also work, I avoid reparsing declaration's by caching the `SourceFile` directly, that also seems to work. I haven't used the language service and this way seemed easier.

Comment: This is too slow for my use case, which happens to be the browser. I wish there was a way of doing this without the overhead of having to create a compiler host.

Comment: @Samuel, the overhead is parsing and type checking. The biggest part of that is probably `lib.d.ts` . You can create a minimal `lib.d.ts` that contains the bare minimum of what you need (maybe just primitives like `string`, `number`, `Array`, and maybe without methods), that should make thinks faster.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir that sounds like an interesting experiment and should be enough for my current use case. How could I overwrite `lib.d.ts`?

Comment: @Samuel Added a version with no default lib, let me know if this works ok for you, I am genuinely curious if this works for you, in my testing it was much faster.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir the time actually reduced a lot. Very clever! Where did you acquire knowledge about the compiler's internals, out of curiosity? To be totally honest, I can only test it on node. Apparently `typescript` npm package is not suitable for the browser. I get an internal error when `ts.createCompilerHost({})`. I wonder how much work it would take to extract the exact type matching code out of TypeScript.

Comment: @Samuel I just read the code ;). I made my master's dissertation on the compiler, and use a modified compiler for a project, been tracking it since version `0.9` or so.

Comment: @Samuel It should work in the browser as well, the compiler works fine in the http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/. Probably you need a different host (maybe there already is a `createWebHost` ? don't know and don't have the time to research right now) or you need to take our the parts that use node reading/writing from the host. Taking the type chekert out of the compiler would be a pain I think, the compilation pahses build on top of each other with type checking being the last one. Also creating just the AST in code would be painful and error prone.